Why is my Mesh/clothing piece unable to be moved
im new to blender so im sorry if this question is stupid. im attempting to parent a piece of clothing onto an armature but when i try moving the piece of clothing, so i can put it onto the body, it stays in the same position no matter what i do. the piece of clothing is parented to another armature but im not sure how to unparent it in order to allow me to move said piece of clothing freely. if anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. i can also give any extra info if needed :)

Hello, why is the cloth parented to another armature and not the same armature as the body?
